# The UPDATE queries is 50x slower than its SELECT query

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-5.7

The UPDATE queries is 50x slower than its SELECT query.

I have a table named `sync_read` and the have the following columns

```
id
club_id
created_at
user_id
queue_id
```

The table have the following Indexes:

```
Keyname            Column
club_id            club_id  
user_id            user_id
club-contact       (club_id,user_id)
```

There are around 69K records in that table. My aim is to update the column `queue_id`, of rows with same **(club_id,user_id)** to same number like

```
id | club_id | created_at | user_id | queue_id
1     99        2015-05-05   8994       59294
2     45        2015-05-05   9872       892191
3     99        2015-05-04   8994       59294
```

I am using the below query to update the data

```
UPDATE sync_read,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids,(FLOOR(RAND() * POW(10,6))) AS rand 
       FROM sync_read 
       WHERE club_id = 15085 AND created_at = '2022-03-11 18:50:51'
       GROUP BY club_id, user_id)
        AS grouped
SET sync_read.queue_id = grouped.rand
WHERE sync_read.created_at = '2022-03-11 18:50:51'
  AND sync_read.club_id = 15085
  AND FIND_IN_SET(sync_read.id, grouped.ids) ;

76 rows affected. (Query took 22.2668 seconds.)
```

This seems to be very slow. So I checked the EXPLAIN for that query. The result is like this

[image]

Then I tried to select the same data

```
SELECT * FROM sync_read, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids,(FLOOR(RAND() * POW(10,6))) AS rand 
    FROM sync_read 
    WHERE club_id = 15085 AND created_at = '2022-03-11 18:50:51' 
    GROUP BY club_id, user_id) AS grouped 
    WHERE sync_read.created_at = '2022-03-11 18:50:51' AND sync_read.club_id = 15085 AND FIND_IN_SET(sync_read.id, grouped.ids)

Showing rows 0 - 24 (76 total, Query took 0.5225 seconds.)
```

The result for the EXPLAIN is
[image]

So you can see that the `SELECT` is taking only 0.5 sec, but the `UPDATE` on the same number of rows took 25sec. Why is the UPDATE query considerably slower than the SELECT statement. After seeing the EXPLAIN result I doubt if the MySQL is considering the index correctly

Comment: You should try to make a temp table with your data and join it with the update table and update the data. Also, it could depend if you have foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this would do the job much faster:

```
UPDATE sync_read
    SET sync_read.queue_id = FLOOR(RAND() * POW(10,6))
    WHERE club_id = 15085
      AND created_at = '2022-03-11 18:50:51';
```

That needs

```
INDEX(club_id, created_at)   -- in this order
```

But, does `queue_id` belong in that table??

**Redundancy of queue_id**

Meanwhile, "My aim is to update the column queue_id, of rows with same (club_id,user_id) to same number" sounds like you have `queue_id` repeated across multiple rows.  Remove that column from this table, and put it into a separate table so that it is not repeated.  That table would have 3 columns: (club_id, user_id, queue_id), with the first 2 being the PK.

That may require a JOIN in some other queries.

Comment: This will calculate a new queue number for each entry where he wants them to be the same.

Comment: @Flourid - I need some more context on "he" and "them" and "same".

Comment: You query will calculate a new queue number for each entry, but OP wants a queue number for all entries with the same club_id and user_id. Quote "My aim is to update the column queue_id, of rows with same (club_id,user_id) to same number"

Comment: @Flourid - Well, I addressed your Comment, but I am not more confused.  Maybe you can take my idea and build a better Answer?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but why not use a composite key for the queue_id, generated from club_id and user_id? You can even add it to your table like this:

```
alter table sync_read add column gen_queue_id bigint as (concat(club_id,user_id));
```